# Papertrading stock exchange application with custom data

Tags: conceptual

I am interested in making a stock exchange web application. The stock will be product like for example liquor but not limited to this category.

An example of what I want to create is something like this:
[Stock Exchange Bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhHsY-SVgfc)

The problem is that I hardly have an idea of how the stock market works. I have quite a lot of programming experience though.

Could somebody maybe explain an extremely simply version of how the prices fluctuates based on the given example?

(I don't know if this is the right place to ask for something like this, if it is not then I am sorry in advance.)

Comment: Are you asking how do market and stock exchange work and which events affect item prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have an ebay auction. But instead of just having buyers bid for a particular good, you also have sellers offering the good... and when they agree you have a purchase, but the auction keeps going... That is basically how a continuous double auction market works.